# elasticsearch When importing data, the CPU reaches 90%

Tags: elasticsearch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttZIV.png)
I am new to elasticsearch
elasticsearch When importing data, the CPU reaches 90%
also,the amount of data I import is very large

elasticsearch  version : 7.17.5

What is the reason and how can I optimize it?

Comment: Run [hot threads](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-hot-threads.html) a few times while elasticsearch is at high load and post the output here, that might provide a better clue on where CPU spends most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons behind high cpu usage in elasticsearch. Scaling up your cluster could be a good option. Here's a great blog that you can follow to reduce excessive cpu usage: [reduce-elasticsearch-high-cpu-usage](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/operations/elasticsearch-high-cpu/)